# Django-CMS plugin cmsplugin_blog is throwing a VariableDoesNotExist error

Tags: django, django-cms

I've been working on a site with Django-CMS running Django 1.4 on Windows 7. After the cmsplugin-blog app is installed and everything's in place, I get this error when trying to add a new blog page (at http://localhost.com/admin/cmsplugin_blog/entry/add/)

**VariableDoesNotExist at /admin/cmsplugin_blog/entry/add/**

Failed lookup for key [MEDIA_URL] in u"[{'csrf_token': , 'use_missing': True}]"

...

**Error during template rendering**

In template C:\dev\virtualenvs\djangocmsenv\Lib\site-packages\cmsplugin_blog\templates\admin\cmsplugin_blog\admin_helpers.html, error at line 2

**(Could not get exception message)**

```
{% if use_missing %}

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL|default:MEDIA_URL }}missing/n11ndata.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL|default:MEDIA_URL }}missing/n11n.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL|default:MEDIA_URL }}missing/urlify2.js"></script>
{% endif %}
```

The creator of the plugin suggested me to add a media or static context processor, but I already had that in place

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'cms.context_processors.media',
    'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
)
```

Here's my static/media root/url setup

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "media")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "static"),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.comments',
    'cms',
    'mptt',
    'cmsplugin_blog',
    'djangocms_utils',
    'simple_translation',
    'tagging',
    'missing',
    'menus',
    'south',
    'sekizai',
    'cms.plugins.googlemap',
    'cms.plugins.link',
    'cms.plugins.picture',
    'cms.plugins.text',
    'cms.plugins.video',
    'cms.plugins.twitter',
    'cmsplugin_contact',
    'carouselplugin',
    'tinymce',
    'django.contrib.admin',
)
```

Could anyone please give me a hand. Thanks.

P.S. the url is actually 127.0.0.1 not localhost.com. Had to change it because I can't submit my question otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the latest version from GitHub repository. The version you have is latest from PyPi which was released before Django 1.4 and is for Django CMS 2.2 (which is for Django 1.3).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not loading static at the top of your template file:

```
{% load static %}
{% get_static_prefix as STATIC_URL %}
```

Comment: the thing is this error only appears when I try to add a new entry to cmsplugin-blog. All my other pages are working correctly, and I never modified the plugin's templates, just followed the docs step by step.

Comment: Ok, getting the latest version from github seem to solve the problem. Thanks.